# Saving JPA object defiened on other project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Good night,

I have some issue that i can't find some way to solve.

I have two Java web projects that i use jpa with hibernate, on the first project i have the annotaded pojo and all the logic to save and create data, on the second project i have a copy of the same POJO but without any annotations.

Still in the second project i defined the persistence.xml with two persistences units, which one of then is linked to the database of the first project.

When i try to create and save and object of that simple POJO in the second project i get the Unknown Entity  Exception, and i can't save the object anyway on the method merge.

I don't know if the problem is the difference between the two pojo's or something else, if someone pass thru this and could give me some tips i will aprecciate.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is the missing annotations on POJOs in the second project. You have to let Hibernate know what POJOs it should manage.